# hibernate won't create table

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

*I got the following in an entity.

```
@Entity("User")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="FrameworkUser_Properties")
    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
       return properties;
    }
    public void setProperties(Map<String, String> properties) {
       this.properties = properties;
    }
}
```

i get the following error

```
Unsuccessful: create table FrameworkUser_Properties (User_id int not null, properties varchar(255) null, properties_KEY varchar(255) null, primary key (User_id, properties_KEY))
```

Anyone got any idea how i should do so is properties_KEY is not null instead?
I use Hibernate Hibernate 3.6.5.Final, MSSQL

//Trind

Comment: Is the question how to define properties_KEY so it is declared in create table statement as null or is the question why table cannot be created?

Comment: I wanted it to be possible to create the table. Ken Chan soloved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are mapping the collection of the value type using the hashmap  . You have to specify the key column of  the hashmap using `@MapKeyColumn`

For example , you can try it to see if the problem can be solved:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name="FrameworkUser_Properties")
@MapKeyColumn
public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
           return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive you can do something like this:

```
 @CollectionTable(
        name="FrameworkUser_Properties",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID", nullable = false)
  )
```